# Navigation Drawer Below Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am trying to get the navigation drawer to open below the toolbar.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
</ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How do I reformat the xml so that the navigation bar opens below the toolbar?

Comment: @tyczj if you look at the latest version of the Google Play store. The navigation drawer is below the toolbar. I would like to implement something similar to that.

Comment: @tyczj How do I handle toolbar actions when the navigation bar is open

Comment: you dont, if you have actions you want the user to do when the drawer is open then you should put them in the drawers layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make DrawerLayout to display below the Toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464326/how-do-i-make-drawerlayout-to-display-below-the-toolbar)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You should move `DrawerLayout` as top parent and move `Toolbar` out of `DrawerLayout` content container.
In short this looks like:

```
RelativeLayout
 ----Toolbar
 ----DrawerLayout
     ---ContentView
     ---DrawerList
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background_color" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, Material Design guidelines state that Navigation Drawer should be above the `Toolbar`.

Comment: This will allow me to handle toolbar actions even when the drawer is open?

Comment: Yes. Because the drawer will only respond to events to the Rect it is bounded.

Comment: But the status bar is overlapping the Toolbar now. How to resolve this?

Comment: @Diffy, you need to ask different question. However, seems that you have problem with your theme, otherwise, wrap the toolbar with padding View of size 25dp.

Comment: fitsystemwindows set to true causes that problem. Resolved anyway.

Comment: Excellent answer Nikola! just a **little improvement**. For the ListView use `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` and in the toolbar set the same value as height.

Comment: You can end up in a trouble where you will not get any clicks in the layout included inside. :(
AM still trying to find out a way to get that sorted.

Answer (score 24):

You should simply add

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
```

to your layout which you are using as drawer.

This will automatically adjust the navigation drawer below the toolbar and also supports different screen sizes.

Comment: Unfortunately, `@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material` is marked as private in the compatibility library, so this solution is unsafe to use as the resource name may disappear in a future release of the library.

Comment: It still creates a shadow on the toolbar when sliding out. Thats not a desired effect. Not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 19):

You can add `layout_marginTop` like this,

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

but drawer will appear as a the top layer to tool bar.

---

Here is another Choppy way to add it below to toolbar!!!

> might not be the best but it works!

*end result will look like this*

[image]

If you create a project as a Navigation Drawer project(`Navigation Drawer Activity`) it will give you four XML files at the creation in your `layout` folder

- app_bar_main
- content_main
- navigatin_main
- activity_main

  [image]

*how these xmls are linked?* mostly i see  `include tag` is used

Your Activity is linked with activity_main

- `activity_main` has the `app_bar_main` and `navigation_view`(drawer)
- `app_bar_main` has the `toolbar` and `content_main`  by default

now lets remove `activity_main` and set its contents directly to app bar main and use it as the main layout for Activity.

To add the drawer under tool bar 
add it under the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` because is contains the toolbar and its should be on top.

here is an example of app_bar_main.XML

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="none.navhead.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    //------ taken from activity_main
    // content main
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    // you need this padding
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

p.s you can set app_bar_main.XML to setContentView of your activity
  just play around there are plenty of ways ;)

Comment: This one works for me also on API23, where NavigationView is designed to be drawn behind system status bar. However, it still had shadow drawn at top, as if it was still drawn behind status bar, so I had to add app:insetForeground="@null" to the NavigationView, and it's drawn correctly below action bar (or actually Toolbar).
This way also the nicely animated arrow at top left is visible, not covered by the NavigationView.

Comment: Also i need to add `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to `DrawerLayout`, to make content and navigation visible properly.

Comment: when i use this then data in fragment is un-clickable. plz say how to solve

Comment: @roshan posakya where did you place your fragment?

Comment: @Charuka thanks to reply ,, but i solve this problem using different way..

Comment: @PointerNull your `app:insetForeground="@null"` saved my day . it will hide that shadow above drawer.

Answer (score 9):

this is my layouts and work perfect:
activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- AppBarLayout should be here -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context=".activty.MainActivity">
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

result:
Bellow toolbar

[image]

Comment: This one works for putting it under a collapsing toolbar with a collapsing image. It stays under the image.

Comment: Perfect. It should work for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using custom toolbar then use the drawer layout in this way..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- drawer view -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start">
            ....
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and if you are not using custom toolbar then you have to set margin top to the drawer layout..

```
android:layout_marginTop ="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

Answer (score 0):

An Easy and Good solution is set `fitsSystemWindows=false` for

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

that has id as

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
```

And for `navigationView` set `layout_marginTop` as `?attr/actionBarSize` that would get the actionbar size and set it as margin

[Here is complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810384/how-to-put-navigation-drawer-below-toolbar/46738805#46738805) of `activity_main.xml` that has both the changes listed above.