# Drawer below title app

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I use next code to show a drawer layout in my application. I need to display the drawer under title bar. But always get it over title.
I can't figure out where I do my mistake.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/top"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and app bar code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="ro.ghiduldrumetului.calauza.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985270/navigation-drawer-below-toolbar

Comment: do you have toolbar implemented

Comment: Tested that solution with same result. RelativeLayout don't help me.

Comment: I tested cuoka solution and it work partialy. Now it work how I want but not display the top area where can see battery or connecton etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
</ListView>
```

Comment: if I try to    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> in Framelayout my app crash.

Comment: what is app bar main ?

Comment: can you paste screen shot or something

Comment: I posted up the app bar. Sorry for stupid questions and acting but I am new to android :) I am just a fanatic hiker and want to do an application to can share with my group my tracking in nature :) But for me all these are alien language.