# Android navigation view has a row on top that won't go

Tags: android, navigationview

I'm making a activity with a navigation view, and in the drawer I keep getting a grey line at the top (before all menu items) which I can't figure out how to remove. I've tried everything but I'm unsuccessful...

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI02J.png)

**My navigation view element**

```xml
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:layout_gravity="start|top"

    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_text"
            android:id="@+id/navigation"/>
```

Comment: It would be useful to mention what have you tried so far.

Comment: I tried searching all over and found nothing. So I've tried with no items, and I've also tried using the layout inspector to find the cause for this line, but nothing pointed to the line :/

Comment: I got it fixed. I put the navigation view in the coordinator layout, turns out it won't work properly when inside it...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985270/navigation-drawer-below-toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
```