# Android navigation drawer without actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I created am navigation drawer activity on Android Studio, but my theme as no ActionBar (I'm using the `Toolbar` widget due to design), and it refuses to work, giving me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` point at here:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
```

So I tried to replace `getActionBar().getThemedContext()` with other context getter functions, but got no sucess...

**Edit:** As requested:
Stacktrace:

```
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.net.beno.supercarrinho/br.net.beno.supercarrinho.AtividadePrincipal}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.net.beno.supercarrinho.AtividadePrincipal.onCreate(AtividadePrincipal.java:52)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.net.beno.supercarrinho.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:100)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1287)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2243)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:278)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:78)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.net.beno.supercarrinho.AtividadePrincipal.onCreate(AtividadePrincipal.java:52) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
10-13 15:15:16.054 15849-15849/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.java:

```
package br.net.beno.supercarrinho;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

AtividadePrincipal.java

```
package br.net.beno.supercarrinho;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import br.net.beno.supercarrinho.R;
import com.digits.sdk.android.Digits;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class AtividadePrincipal extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    // Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
    private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "Dwt1PeE72Ht0znFw1WjVD7ym3";
    private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "NjxKx3fSfVI5DJ1xcuC5Eqy7AMPaJV5K1kzsCPYIdmxXWeNfoI";


    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Digits(), new Twitter(authConfig));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_atividade_principal);

        // Trocando a actionbar pela toolbar
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        // Gaveta de navegacao

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, FragmentoListaCompras.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.atividade_principal, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit 3:**

activity_atividade_principal.xml:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.net.beno.supercarrinho.AtividadePrincipal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="bottom" />

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="br.net.beno.supercarrinho.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If you need anything more, please ask. :)

Comment: This code is not enough the get a clue of your null pointer. Please post the full stack trace and some context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thanks for some comments and replies here, and some extra research, I was able to enable it.

As [user5195185](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5195185/user5195185) pointed out, it seems like the `DrawerLayout` **must** have only two children: The content (the view where it will attach whatever content you put), and the drawer (the `ListView`). After some search on Github, I got [this code](https://github.com/lfq7413/Material-framwork/blob/3794ca35e8c87d7a77679446ef057816a1d32811/res/layout/activity_setting.xml).

So I put my `Toolbar` widget with the default `FrameLayout` inside a `LinearLayout`, but I still got the same NullPointer error...

Then I inspected it's code, and I found that they passed the main activity as the context, so I used `getActivity()` instead of `getActionBar().getThemedContext()` as the context, and it worked!

After that, I found [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26555224/1347214), to allow the bar to stay above the ListView, and I was set.

So, I don't know if it may lead to future problems, but is seems as the right way to get the Toolbar and the NavigationDrawer to work together.

Answer (score 1):

Before you invoke `getActionBar()` or `getSupportActionbar()`, you should set your `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar`.

Have you already set the `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar` in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` before the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView` is called?

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar_id);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
// setActionBar(toolbar); // if you are not using AppCompatActivity
```

**EDIT:**

> NavigationDrawerFragment's onCreateView is called first...

Then you may well move these lines:

```
// Trocando a actionbar pela toolbar
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

to the Fragment:

```
private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    activity.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    return activity.getSupportActionBar();
}
```

There may be still some error with above code, however in this order the `ActionBar` won't be null.

Comment: I saw your updated post. However, if your Fragment is populated in the `R.layout.activity_atividade_principal`, its `onCreateView` may go ahead. Please check which is earlier by inserting `Log.d()`s in the `onCreateView` and just before `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a try.

Comment: No go... `activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` returns null... The toolbar is on `activity_atividade_principal.xml`. I inspected the `activity`, and it returned an `AtividadePrincipal` object...

Answer (score 1):

**((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()**
the action bar is a part of the activity, not the fragment. Watch every line in your fragment class where you accessed action bar. Also, as you are extending AppCompatActivity for the activity, you must use getSupportActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout should have only two children: main content and the navigation view. I think that toolbar is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

In activity_main.xml, add code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

In NavigationDrawerFragment.java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;


mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    Toolbar mToolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

  mToolbar,
  //R.drawable.ic_drawer,
```