# Android Studio NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In Android Studio when create a new project the Android Studio suggest Activity.
in Navigation Drawer Activity i want the Drawer Toggle has shown but to Default mode it hidden under navigation.

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); 
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close); 
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle); 
toggle.syncState();
```

please help that change it to show drawer toggle...

Comment: Please post your activity code

Comment: this Default code my friend...:
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464326/how-do-i-make-drawerlayout-to-display-below-the-toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do changes in activity_main.xml

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#adfcdd"
        android:layout_height="50dp"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: WOWWWW Thank A Lot This solved My problem....

Comment: Then marked it as Correct and give it vote.

Comment: OK This Solved My Problem...Very  Very Thanks
But Auto Cancel Not work.