# Coloring Android Status Bar in Nav Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

In this app I'm building, I've added a Navigation Drawer fragment into my activity. I'm using 5.0, so I've been able to set the primaryColor and primaryColorDark to get the right colors. I've decided to try and style my Nav Drawer to be very similar to Google Now's drawer in 5.0, where the Nav Drawer has it's own background for the status bar. (Can't post pictures, not enough reputation >.>)

I've followed this question's recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st), which has helped quite a bit. I've achieved drawing my Nav Drawer under the status bar when I pull it out. Only trouble is, I can't figure out how to set the color of the status bar that shows in my drawer. Currently, it just shows white.

Here are the relevant bits of my styles and code:

Activity Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- main content -->
    ...

    <!-- Drawer fragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:theme="@style/DrawerTheme"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:name="com.myname.appname.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navDrawerFragment"
    android:theme="@style/DrawerTheme"
    android:background="@color/WindowBackground"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <!-- content here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Per link above, setting color of my status bar for the activity (this part works correctly):

```
public void onCreate(Bundled savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ....

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, Gravity.START);
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    // ....
}
```

And finally, my associated styles for the activity, and what I've 'tried' to assign to the fragment.

```
<style name="StatusBarActivityTheme" parent="MyAppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>


<style name="DrawerTheme" parent="MyAppTheme">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can send my way! I suspect my issue is related to do with how Google Now's primary screen has a transparent status bar, and only colors it during the Nav Drawer, but any news to the contrary would be great!

Comment: R.color.colorPrimaryDark is referencing a color value from your app XML, not the android:colorPrimaryDark theme attribute. What have you defined @color/colorPrimaryDark as in your res files?

Comment: I've defined @color/colorPrimaryDark to a hex color, can't think of it off the top of my head. That part is working - it's correctly coloring the activity (drawerlayout's) status bar. I'm more concerned about the fragment drawer. (I REALLY wish I could post some screencaps, but this is my first post...)

Comment: DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor() is the correct method call to set the drawer's status bar color. You don't need to set a special theme on it. Does getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark) resolve to white?

Comment: R.color.colorPrimaryDark is set in colors.xml, with this declaration:     <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303f9f</color>. It's setting the status bar color for the top-container in the Activity's Layout (activity_main.xml). What isn't being colored is the status bar portion of the fragment. I realized I can use imgur, so here's what it looks like: http://imgur.com/5rbKnZb. Right is the main content, and left is the fragment nav drawer.

Comment: Oh, also, this is the effect from Google Now that I'm trying to achieve. Again, left is the Nav Drawer, and right is the content. http://imgur.com/gC4s0YB

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the setup you have, the Nav Drawer is simply a view drawing its background (which you have defined as `android:background="@color/WindowBackground"`) underneath the status bar (the color of which you have set to transparent via your `StatusBarActivityTheme`). The system only looks as far as the Activity theme to set the status bar color; assigning `android:statusBarColor` to a child has no effect.

The simple solution would be to **change your Nav Drawer fragment layout's `android:background` to the color you desire**. If you wish for the portion below your image to remain white, an option would be to then add an empty View in your drawer layout with `android:background="@color/WindowBackground"` or some other color.

---

If you desire for the *content* in your Nav Drawer to extend below the status bar, it requires a bit more work. The reason it is offset to begin with is because you set the `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute to true, which in turn calls the view's default [fitSystemWindows()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#fitSystemWindows(android.graphics.Rect)). As the docs explain, this method takes the inset (i.e. the height of the status bar in our case) and applies it as the view's padding (in your case, this becomes top padding for the `RelativeLayout` of your Nav Drawer fragment).

One way to circumvent this padding is to overwrite the view's `fitSystemWindows()` method. I direct you to the open source IO Schedule app by Google - specifically, they used the [`ScrimInsetsScrollView`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsScrollView.java) as the root element in their [Nav Drawer](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/navdrawer.xml). This modified `ScrollView` applies a scrim of a color of your choice (set via the custom `app:insetForeground` attribute) and *consumes* the inset, i.e. no more padding!

The `ScrimInsetsScrollView` can be used as a model to write your own version for any View descendant, really - see the nigh identical [`ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java).

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote the answer, but I've only got 3 rep still.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the background of Navigation drawer's root view and it worked :)