# how to achieve the status bar that is like subtransparent above and a view in colorprimarydark under

Tags: android, android-studio, android-statusbar

I want to achieve status bar that just likes the drawer layout achieved by android studio automatically.
it looks like status bar have a subtransparent view that has the text and icon(e.g electric quantity..) on it. and it seems like there is a view in colorprimarydark under the subtransparent view just providing the background.
just like this two pictures

[the status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbJ2s.jpg)

[when open the navigationview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llUuv.jpg)

i checked the code produced by android studio

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

can work only in the mainactivity(drawerlayout), for others the first line seems to cover the second, all their status bar is transparent and in the color of the layout background.
how can i achieve the status bar..

Comment: is the drawerlayout that playing a part in the status bar?

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745300/navigation-drawer-semi-transparent-over-status-bar-not-working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568428/coloring-android-status-bar-in-nav-drawer