# Activity could not be started due to support ActionBar's class cast exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar, classcastexception, android-styles

From one android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity I'm starting another android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity activity, but  getting this Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.playgong.stg.dbg, PID: 32299
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.applyInsets(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:172)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:317)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

First activity has style

```
<style name="PS" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Second (that which is crashing):

```
<style name="PS.Second" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/PS.ActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas how to avoid `ClassCastException`?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/26577461/603744

Comment: Is this crashing in all Devices or something specific ?

Comment: Also could you post the `PS.ActionBar` style ?

Comment: Mention the API version, the support library version and the device you are using. This would help walkthrough the code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is `PS.ActionBar` style. So I commented that out. And tried the same thing on my Device Moto G API 21. I don't see the crash.

That being said, this crash appears to be an internal one. Besides `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated, instead use `AppCompatActivity`.

PS: I am still waiting for your answer, so I could edit my answer with more findings.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was not using a activity theme which has no action bar.  Using the following theme set in the manifest for the activity works:

```xml
<style name="mytheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

the other pecular thing is that it only occured on kitkat.