# How to add the Navigation Drawer to Multiple Activites

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have an app in which I added the `Navigation Drawer` by looking at the example android studio gives you. But now I want to add the drawer to other activities. To try to do this, I made an new project with the `Navigation Drawer Activity` that Android Studio gives you. I found that the easiest way to achieve this is to
make a `BaseActivity` and extends all my other activities that need a `Navigation Drawer` from the `BaseActivity` Here is some of my code.

**BaseActivity.java**

```
package com.example.eddie.drawerapp2;
//I did not include the imports to make this shorter

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private NavigationView navView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

**activity_base.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I go to `activity_base.xml` and change it to design view it looks fine.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.eddie.drawerapp2;

//skip imports

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //inflate your activity layout here!
        drawer = (findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
        drawer.addView(contentView, 0);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eddie.drawerapp2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.eddie.drawerapp2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java` have logic error. It just displays the content, and a blank tool bar. Swiping to open the `NavigationDrawer` doesn't do anything either. I really do not know what to do, this was just my attempt. Please help me, I am really stuck.  What do I need to do to add the `NavigationDrawer` to the `MainActivity` and than other activities?

Comment: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main` ... Why? `setContentView` is already inflating a View for you...

Comment: See XML here for main activity... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635485/using-appcompat-toolbar-with-framelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before, I think what you lack in your code for BaseActivity.java is overiding the setContentView methods so that content view can be set into the framelayout creating the behaviour of other activity implement this like subclasses.

1.
 **BaseActivity.java**

```
package com.example.eddie.drawerapp2;
//I did not include the imports to make this shorter

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private NavigationView navView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

     /* Overriding all setContentView methods to put the content view to the FrameLayout frameLayout
  * so that, we can make other activity implementations looks like normal activity subclasses.
  */

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    if (frameLayout != null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        View stubView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, false);
        frameLayout.addView(stubView, lp);
    }
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    if (frameLayout != null) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        frameLayout.addView(view, lp);
    }
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (frameLayout != null) {
        frameLayout.addView(view, params);
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

2. Your MainActivity.java should something look like this
   **MainActivity.java**

   ```
   package com.example.eddie.drawerapp2;

   //skip imports

   public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

       private DrawerLayout drawer;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       }
    }
   ```

3.
 **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really appreciate it. One thing, in the ends of each `setContentView` method `super.setContentView` needs to be called. This gets the app to run, but it does not make the drawer work. Everything with `toolbar` had to be moved from `baseActivity` to `MainActivity.onCreate()`. as well as the `NavigationView` also had to be copied from `activity_base` to `activity_main`

Comment: well thats interesting because that never happened in my case, especially with the navigationView. And in my case I completely removed the Toolbar. but I think you may hace to do some overrides for those as well in the BaseActivity.java

Comment: I did everythin like in the example you provided, and it cashes saying Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference and points to this `drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);` in `BaseActivity` Can you please help

Comment: ok will upload the codes of that project to github and share the link. I dont mind since it was strictly for educational purposes