# Dark tinted status bar over navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have implemented a navigation drawer with material design as per [How do I use DrawerLayout to display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st) however because my drawer is white this causes issue with the status bar. The Google I/O 2014 application tints the status bar over the navigation drawer, how does it achieve this? I cannot find how in it's source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google IO 2014 app uses a [ScrimInsetsFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java) to tint the status bar (and the navigation drawer will cover the status bar). I highly recommend to use it I've tried a lot and it works best! ;-)

To get the ScrimInsetsFrameLayout to work you'll need to do four things:

1.) Add the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` class to your project.

2.) Use the ScrimInsetsFrameLayout as root-element **of your drawer list** in the xml-file of your activity. Important: Set `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `true` for **both** the `DrawerLayout` and the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`

3.) In your **activity theme (-v21) xml** add the line `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`. (Otherwise, the 'normal' status bar will overlay the status bar of the ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.)

4.) In your activity, initialize the drawer and the `DrawerLayout` as usual, and then call
`drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color)` to color the status bar.

In the Google IO App, this is done in the `setupNavDrawer()` method of the [BaseActivity](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java)