# Strange padding on the bottom after hide and show the fragment using the transparent status bar in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation

I used the way https://stackoverflow.com/a/27051852/3875363 to achieve the drawer behind the status bar, it seems fine before only stay for one view.

But I faced a strange case after I hide and show this fragment, a white padding appears on the bottom of the drawerlayout, it likes below.

[image]

I comment most codes to show a simple example.

The layout of activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

The layout of fragment with drawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_in_list"
            layout = "@layout/toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.ghostflying.portalwaitinglist.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/debug_content"
        android:background="@color/setting_item_group_title_text"
        app:insetForeground="#4000"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width">

    </com.ghostflying.portalwaitinglist.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The layout of the second fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Once I hide the drawer fragment, show the second fragment, then I popup the back stack to return. The drawer fragment will seem like the image, a padding with the height of status bar always appear. So strange.

Comment: have you solved it

Answer (score 0):

*Try to remove `android:paddingBottom` from `DrawerLayout`.
`android:paddingTop` makes Drawer doesn't cover the Status Bar, but there is no reason to duplicate padding at the bottom.*

**EDIT:**
After your update, I analyzed it once more and I think your issue can be caused by your unusual design. All guides suggest that `DrawerLayout` should be **root element** of view hierarchy (as in your example you provided). See here: [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

So I suggest one of these solutions.

1. Use **separate Activities** to display Views **with and without Drawer**. (I recommend this, especially when your Drawer plays navigational role.)
2. Use **one Activity** with Drawer Layout as root and **put Fragments as Drawer's main content**. If you don't want Drawer to be openable use this method after changing Fragment:
   `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

Comment: In fact, the padding is all 0dp, I comment most codes, it seems also very strange, I'll edit the question later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the android attribute:

```
fitsSystemWindows = "true"
```

This worked for me.

According to the official documentation it's a

> Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system
>   windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this
>   view to leave space for the system windows.