# Navigation Drawer Below of StatusBar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

Since the last update to support library, the Navigation Drawer Appears Below Status Bar. I have tried every possible way that I can to resolve this problem, but couldn't solved it.

I solved it by using WindowTranslucentStatus, but I don't want to use as it makes the status bar too dark than primaryDark.

Any Help is Highly Appreciated!!
[image]

Comment: put DrawerLayout below ToolBar

Comment: Tried it..Didn't Helped.

Comment: Try
<style name="YourTheme.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>

Comment: you want drawer below toolbar or status bar?

Comment: Consider using Material Drawer by @Mike https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer . It does everything for you

Comment: @AdityaVyas I want it below Status Bar.

Comment: @Vivek_Neel I have used Mike Penz's Material Drawer Before then migrated to support library.

Comment: @Ram I Solved it windowTranslucentStatus before, but I don't want to use it as it make StatusBar too dark.

Comment: @Haroon http://pastebin.com/raw/t3KsDEsT

Comment: @PrasadShirvandkar  `I want it below Status Bar....` . Well, it is *supposed* to show below status bar and does so. What is the question then ?

Comment: Status Bar or Title Bar?

Comment: @S.D. It is supposed to show below Status Bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put Navigation Drawer Under Status Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271251/put-navigation-drawer-under-status-bar)

Comment: The XML looks fine. Can you  remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  from all elements except root element i.e drawerLayout and check

Comment: @Haroon Nothing Happened.

Comment: @PrasadShirvandkar Status bar is the one with battery, network and other icons. It does not belong to app, it is part of system UI. Below it is the space of your app's activity, there you have ActionBar or Toolbar. The drawer can be configured to cover ActionBar/Toolbar, not the Status bar. You can make the activity cover all the status bar by setting it to full screen mode.

Comment: @S.D. I Know that.. But my previous version that is on Play Store is fine with Navigation Drawer..when I updated my support library this issue came up.

Comment: Bro i updated the Library , and below snip is  working  fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/aapBar"/>

<!--</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aapBar">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>-->


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    style="@style/NavigationTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Design Support Library version:  'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

With  this it Works fine can you take this snip and adjust your layouts accordingly if makes sense

Comment: I believe it has to do with your layout arrangements

Comment: I haven't changed my layout files since last version of my app which is on the play store and it is fine on the play store version.

Comment: Do you have rollback option , to fetch the same code base , though it seems strange

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionbarDrawerToggle like this

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /*
                             * nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret
                             */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
             */
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

            }
        };
```