# set status bar color in DrawerLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

I want to set status bar color in my custom `DrawerLayout` like default navigation drawee. It work perfectly but `DraweeLayout` should be behind status bar and status bar color should be custom.
Below is my v21\style.

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/orange</item>
</style>
```

Here is activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llFirst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/menu" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvLeft"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        />    
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener {

    private MyAdapter drawerLayoutAdapter;
    private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
    private ImageView imgMenu;
    private ArrayList<String> alTemp;
    private ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList;
    private ExpandableListView expandbleLis;

    private Activity activity;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setId();
        setListner();
        setSliderColor();
        slideMenu();
        loadArraylist();
        drawerLayoutAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
        expandbleLis.setAdapter(drawerLayoutAdapter);
        expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setListner()
    {
        imgMenu.setOnClickListener(this);

        // it is used to close all child view on expandable listview and show only one childview at a time.
        expandbleLis.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousGroup = -1;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                    expandbleLis.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                previousGroup = groupPosition;
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadArraylist()
    {

        arrayList = new ArrayList<MyModel>();
        alTemp = new ArrayList<>();

        //here we have pur zero position blank because on zero position we will be put profile picture layout.
        arrayList.add(new MyModel("", 0, alTemp));

        alTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        alTemp.add("My Profile");
        arrayList.add(new MyModel("Profile", R.drawable.profile, alTemp));

        alTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        alTemp.add("My Transaction");

        arrayList.add(new MyModel("Transaction History", R.drawable.transaction, alTemp));

        alTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        alTemp.add("My Setting");
        arrayList.add(new MyModel("Setting", R.drawable.setting, alTemp));

        alTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        alTemp.add("Logout");
        arrayList.add(new MyModel("Log out", R.drawable.logout, alTemp));
    }


    private void slideMenu()
    {
        try
        {
            DrawerLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) expandbleLis.getLayoutParams();
            expandbleLis.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            expandbleLis.setAdapter(drawerLayoutAdapter);

            if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(expandbleLis))
            {
                drawer_layout.closeDrawer(expandbleLis);
            }

            expandbleLis.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos, long id)
                {
                    drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
                        {
                            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

                        }
                    });
                    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(expandbleLis);
                    displayView(pos);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void displayView(final int positionTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            closeDrawer();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    switch (positionTitle)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, 200);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setId()
    {
        try
        {
            drawer_layout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            imgMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMenu);

            // below is for expandable listview.
            expandbleLis = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLeft);
            expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(1);
            expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);   // it is used to hide expandable list symbol.
            expandbleLis.setClickable(true);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void openDrawer()
    {
        try
        {
            expandbleLis.invalidateViews();
            drawer_layout.openDrawer(expandbleLis);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeDrawer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(expandbleLis))
            {
                drawer_layout.closeDrawer(expandbleLis);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.imgMenu:

                openDrawer();

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked On Child",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Actually I want to implement custom Drawer layout in which status bar color should be custom as well as Drawer layout should be behind of status bar which will semi transparent. Here I have attach picture and I want to implement as same. I have try almost every solution but not get any proper result so please help me to solve such issue. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`.

Here is Custom `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` class with which you can implement this kind of behaviour

**ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java**

```
public class ScrimInsetsFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private Drawable mInsetForeground;

    private Rect mInsets;
    private Rect mTempRect = new Rect();
    private OnInsetsCallback mOnInsetsCallback;

    public ScrimInsetsFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public ScrimInsetsFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ScrimInsetsFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ScrimInsetsView, defStyle, 0);
        if (a == null) {
            return;
        }
        mInsetForeground = a
                .getDrawable(R.styleable.ScrimInsetsView_insetForeground1);
        a.recycle();

        setWillNotDraw(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
        mInsets = new Rect(insets);
        setWillNotDraw(mInsetForeground == null);
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        if (mOnInsetsCallback != null) {
            mOnInsetsCallback.onInsetsChanged(insets);
        }
        return true; // consume insets
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        if (mInsets != null && mInsetForeground != null) {
            int sc = canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(getScrollX(), getScrollY());

            // Top
            mTempRect.set(0, 0, width, mInsets.top);
            mInsetForeground.setBounds(mTempRect);
            mInsetForeground.draw(canvas);

            // Bottom
            mTempRect.set(0, height - mInsets.bottom, width, height);
            mInsetForeground.setBounds(mTempRect);
            mInsetForeground.draw(canvas);

            // Left
            mTempRect
                    .set(0, mInsets.top, mInsets.left, height - mInsets.bottom);
            mInsetForeground.setBounds(mTempRect);
            mInsetForeground.draw(canvas);

            // Right
            mTempRect.set(width - mInsets.right, mInsets.top, width, height
                    - mInsets.bottom);
            mInsetForeground.setBounds(mTempRect);
            mInsetForeground.draw(canvas);

            canvas.restoreToCount(sc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (mInsetForeground != null) {
            mInsetForeground.setCallback(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mInsetForeground != null) {
            mInsetForeground.setCallback(null);
        }
    }

    public void setOnInsetsCallback(OnInsetsCallback onInsetsCallback) {
        mOnInsetsCallback = onInsetsCallback;
    }

    public static interface OnInsetsCallback {
        public void onInsetsChanged(Rect insets);
    }
}
```

Now Regarding Use of this class.

**-> activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_headers"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_header"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <yourpackagename.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground1="#4000" >

        <!-- this would be your custom drawer layout -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/drawar_layout"
            layout="@layout/drawar_layout" />
    </bhagyagold.com.extraclasses.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here impotent tag is `android:fitsSystemWindows` check this in all views carefully.

**-> java part**

finally open or close your drawer with this layout.

for e.g

```
mLayout = (ScrimInsetsFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLayout);
```

**-> styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

**EDIT :**

**-> attrs.xml**

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="ScrimInsetsView">
        <attr name="insetForeground1" format="reference|color" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Happy coding..

Comment: Hello Mr Purohit, Thanks for help me but In `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` class is not working properly show error in 40th line [like](https://drive.google.com/a/ifuturz.com/file/d/0B0OXBbfffzFRSE54RUJFY0t3Tmc/view?usp=sharing). Please let me know how to fix such issue.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Purohit, It is working fine. You save my time and solve my problem..Thanks you so much my brother..

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/statusbar_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusbar_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Add that code in your style.XML and then apply in your manifiest in application tag set that theam like  . ..

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: @Akshay....Thanks for help me, I have tried your solution but `DrawerLayout` display below `status bar`. I want to show `status bar` semi transparent like attached image and `DrawerLayout` should be show behind `status bar`.

Comment: @Sakib. . Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913770/make-navigation-drawer-draw-behind-status-bar