# Android windowTranslucentStatus not working with fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, statusbar, transparent, translucentdecor

I have a simple activity with a drawer layout that display a map as content on the right.

I wish to set my status bar a bit transparent so I set this in the styles:

> item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true

It works great but now all my content is BEHIND the status bar and I would like to have it below. After some research some "say" that setting fitsSystemWindows to true on the DrawerLayout properties it will make the content go below. But when I do this it indeed works,the content goes below the status bar... but the status bare becomes solid again.

Comment: is this what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/26952242/6689101

Comment: no it is not...

Comment: Please post your layout.

Comment: Why do you want your status bar transparent and content below it? ... You can add top padding with height of `Status Bar` to your root xml element (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android).

Comment: @skywall that's what fitsSystemWindows is used for. Doing that programmatically is a very bad idea.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Nop... I had gave up