# Nav Drawer on lollipop shows up behind system bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

On Lollipop, in the Gmail app, the nav drawer opens up behind the top status bar. My nav drawer layout is `match_parent`, but it stops below the status bar. Any idea how to accomplish this?

FYI I am using the new Toolbar...

Got this image off the internet, don't mind the image on the right..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440880/961759

Here's a nice open source example on how to accomplish the desired behaviour

https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template