# Lollipop toolbar drawer toggle not clickable

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I can't get the new lollipop drawer toggle to work.

I did this:

```
void setupToolbar() {
    setToolbarAsActionBar();
    setupDrawerToggle();
}

public void setToolbarAsActionBar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

void setupDrawerToggle() {
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.overview_title, R.string.overview_title) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

The hamburger icon is there, I see it animating when sliding drawer out by swiping finger. Still, the icon is not clickable. What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoa, the problem was somewhere we're not watching.

I put the `DrawerLayout` over the `ToolBar` so it was intercepting touch and not let them reach `ToolBar`!

The right layout example for the toolbar under the navigation drawert is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st) as an accepted answer.

Also note:

**Just the ActionBarToggle is enough.**

You don't need either  `onOptionsItemSelected()` nor any of these:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first: put `drawerToggle.syncState();` in `onPostCreate` - common mistake (if you are creating ActionBarDrawerToggle in `onCreate` Activity, it's proper way to do this). then:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) //or other check
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        else
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

edit:

is your ActionBar enabled? pick what you need:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I had syncState on onPostCreate(). Removed second execution from setupDrawerToggle(). I also tried with onOptionsItemSelected() but it's not beeing called (Yes, it's an activity, not a fragment). Clicking on drawer icon gives no response of clicking at all

Comment: Tried that too, no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it using following layout:

i have used ActionBarDrawerToggle v7

Drawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.Drawer" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />



    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- Nav drawer -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app1:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app1:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Drawer.java

package com.example.toolbar;

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Drawer extends ActionBarActivity {

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] days;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

        days = new String[] { "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
                "thursday", "friday", "saturday" };
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, days);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(MyFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, days[position]);
                // args.putInt(MyFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

            }

        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool1);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("ToolBar Demo");
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.open_navigation_drawer,
                R.string.close_navigation_drawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("hello");
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("hi");
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //<---- added
        // getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); //<---- added

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // <---- added
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // <---- added
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState(); // important statetment for drawer to
                                    // identify
                                    // its state
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { // <---- added
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START | Gravity.LEFT)) { // <----
                                                                        // added
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```