# How to create full height Android 5 navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation

I'm searching for a guide, how to create Android 5 style navigation drawer, which covers status bar and bottom controls bar.
Current documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and navigation drawer activity template in Android Studio provides info on how to create old style (Android 4) navigation drawer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use DrawerLayout to display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st)