# setsupportactionbar() throws error

Tags: android, toolbar, android-support-library

I tried following the steps for displaying a drawer above the action bar but below the status bar. The steps found here:
[display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st/26440880#26440880)

But after implementing the code, the following error was thrown:
`error: cannot find symbol method setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`
I've searched on Google for this exact error and not a single result.

I'm using Android Studio (1.1) and have tried using "Clean Build"
I'm using `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //error
```

Hopefully, someone recognizes this error and has a quick answer for it - otherwise I can provide more information if requested.

Comment: your class has to extend `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: @Blackbelt and no more error is thrown - except that the app now crashes instead. But that's another error.  
Submit your comment as an answer, and I could accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**:

Recently `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated in favor of `ActionBarCompat`. You should use the new one, and use as the `ActionBarCompat` themes, E.g. `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

you class has to extend  `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`, in order to use the method `setSupportActionBar`

Answer (score 6):

**Delete:**
import android.widget.Toolbar;

**Add:**
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: This is what fixed it in conjunction with extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: AppCompatActivity should be used instead. The AppcompactActivity is a class which extends FragmentActivity that is Base class for activities that use the support library action bar features. So Activity is faster than all & AppCompatActivity is the best of all.

Answer (score 5):

ActionBarActivity is now deprecated. Use AppCompatActivity instead

Comment: If you're using AppCompatActivity, you also need to be using the theme "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 4):

You must extend your class from `ActionBarActivity` from support package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting it:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar)mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me this work like thi:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```