# Any work arounds to the YoutubePlayerApi extending YoutubeBaseActivity?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have been trying to add a youtube player to a view flipper by following a tutorial. In said tutorial, the activity that handles the youtube player extends YoutubeBaseActivity. This then gives me errors when i try to use setSupportActionBar.
Here are the solutions that i have attempted.

1. I have tried extending YouTubePlayerFragment, which is what an answer to a similar question on here stated, but the errors are still present.
2. I also already imported this

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

3. I have also tried extending 
   `AppBarCompact` as suggested by some answers, but this then makes the Youtube Player not function and the application crushes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is the tutorial I followed (Skip to 9:45): https://youtu.be/W4hTJybfU7s?t=585

These are the relevant lines of code

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

These are my imports

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
//import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".event_customer_view_activity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cust_event_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cust_event_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/flipperid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="330dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:flipInterval="4000"
                android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
                android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"></ViewFlipper>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cust_prev"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp">

                </ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cust_next"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp">

                </ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/venue_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cust_prev"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="Venue: "
                    android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cust_event_venue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/venue_label"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/directions_btn"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cust_next"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@null"

                    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp">

                </ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/venue_label"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="Price: "
                    android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cust_event_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cust_event_venue"
                    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/price_label"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buy_ticket_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/directions_btn"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cust_event_price"
                    android:background="@color/ColorDarkAccent"
                    android:text="Buy Ticket"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cust_event_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/LightText"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the error i am getting:

> error: cannot find symbol method setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)

Comment: Perhaps add a link to said tutorial and add a log of what errors you are getting so we can help you better :)

Comment: @D.Freeman I have made the necessary edits to include the trouble code, tutorial in question and the logcat info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setsupportactionbar() throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150100/setsupportactionbar-throws-error)

Comment: imported package for Toolbar must be import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: @VVB I had already done this. The error is still persisting

Comment: @DaImTo No it doesn't. The answer you have linked is different from mine since OP isn't attempting to implement a Youtube Player.

Comment: Can you post your xml and import section?

Comment: Alternative is you can try YoutubePlayerSupportFragment. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584073/getsupportactionbar-with-youtubebaseactivity

Comment: @VVB i have edited the question to your liking. Your second suggestion has not worked unfortunately.