# Android Toolbar for API 19? (for API 21 works ok)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I used [How do I use DrawerLayout to display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st) 
answer of Suyash (I also added a toolbar, maybe incorrectly) to put Navigation Drawer over the "action bar".

For API level 21 instead of "action bar" I used toolbar, and it works fine.

But for API 19 this is not working:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
      final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

Do you have idea how I can put NavigationDrawer over "actionbar" (or toolbar) for API level 19?

Comment: Before I added toolbar, in the solution of Suyash, it looked just like : hideActionBar + android:windowTranslucentStatus. For api21 action bar dissappeared,  for api19 didn't change except getting grey. Did I do something wrongly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Toolbar then you should be able to view the exact same Toolbar in any API.

For doing that you should have a XML in res/layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

And in your main layout you should include it:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />
```

Also you should set your style as No Action Bar on your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

But for API 21 you should have another styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

And finally in your Main Activity

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And finally to any thing you want to do to the toolbar, obtain it and treat it like the old Action Bar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Changing your theme on API 21 from AppCompat to something else is unnecessary (and actually breaks much of the theming of `ActionBarActivity`).

Comment: Thank you for help. It seemed that I didn't add to styles.xml     <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>.

Comment: @joaquin. I use AppCompat toolbar for my project (like you say). but for lower APIs (lower than 20),my app has stopped.why?

Comment: @MinaDahesh can you provide some useful data? Like the exception you're getting.

Comment: @joaquin.all my activitys extends *AppCompatActivity* . and my app theme is *Theme.AppCompat.Light* .  although i use *setSupportActionBar(toolbar);* but now time, as i run it in api 16, it has stopped.

Comment: @joaquin.                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{PACKAGE}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: @MinaDahesh that's because I'm sure you're not configuring the `styles.xml` file in the correct way. Try to set it up to No Action Bar. Check my answer carefully.

Answer (score 4):

**[Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)** :

> All of your themes (that want an Action Bar/Toolbar) must inherit
> from Theme.AppCompat. There are variants available, including Light
> and NoActionBar.
>
> When inflating anything to be displayed on the action
> bar (such as a SpinnerAdapter for list navigation in the toolbar),
> make sure you use the action bar’s themed context, retrieved via
> getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext().

---

**[Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)** :

> AppCompat allows you to use android:theme for Toolbars (deprecating
> the app:theme used previously) and, even better, brings android:theme
> support to all views on API 11+ devices.

Answer (score 1):

First , you need to add com.android.support:appcombat-v7:25.3.0 as a dependency .  Then import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar to the activity that you want to add the toolbar. With this way you can implement the toolbar for api 19 .

Answer (score 1):

**AndroidX**

If you don't want to use android support library. Here is a better work through now available for this problem

`androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

[Migrating to AndroidX Class Mappings available through this official link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings)

Further you can also directly refractor your whole project to AndroidX from Android Studio:
From Menu you can do
Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX

[More information here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Further, for me the Refractor > Migrate to AndroidX feature did not convert my Toolbars in `xml` to AndroidX so, I found former link really helpful.