# The method setStatusBarBackgroundColor() is undefined for the type DrawerLayout

Tags: android

//Recently, I was learning the Google's Material Design. It's so magic! I saw the [Chris Banes's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st) and I followed the reply. Here is my code:

> public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(100, 100, 100);

}
```

}

//But the method 'setStatusBarBackgroundColor' cannot be used,why?

//my part of xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.example.app.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/base"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000" />
```

// and the styles:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/base</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/base</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the method 'setStatusBarBackgroundColor' cannot be used,why?

Because, as you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setStatusBarBackgroundColor(int)), `setStatusBarBackgroundColor(int)` expects a single int argument representing the color to set:

> `public void setStatusBarBackgroundColor (int color)`
>
> Set a drawable to draw in the insets area for the status bar. Note that this will only be activated if this DrawerLayout fitsSystemWindows.
>
> **Parameters** 
> *color* - Color to use as a background drawable to draw behind the status bar in 0xAARRGGBB format.

However, you're trying to give it 3 arguments:

```
drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(100, 100, 100);
```

Assuming those are RGB values you're trying to set, change the above line to:

```
drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(100, 100, 100));
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I corrected it, but it's still going wrong with the same tips.

Comment: @freshMan: Define "going wrong" please? I.e. copy-paste the exact error your IDE is giving you, or make a screenshot.

Comment: What the IDE gave me is the title above, other than that, nothing else. This problem has troubled me for days.

Comment: @freshMan: What IDE? And what version of the support library do you have?

Comment: The latest version of ADT; sdk:  android:minSdkVersion="21", android:targetSdkVersion="22"; library: android-support-v4.jar. that's all.

Comment: @freshMan: Sorry, but you've failed to answer either question. I'm happy to help out, but I need you to help me here too...

Comment: Thank you for helping me, maybe you feel a bit difficult to understand my words, even though I had tried my best to express my problem. The reason is that my English is poor.I'll try to solve it by myself, thanks all the same.

Comment: @freshMan: You're English is fine. What I'm referring to is that when I ask about your IDE, I would expect to hear Eclipse, Android Studio or IntelliJ. Similarly, when I ask about the support library version, I expect one of the revisions mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance,Reading the document of Support Library, I find out where I was wrong, I copy-paste the file named android-support-v4.jar to my new project, but the version of this file has not been updated for a long time.No matter which version, but at least not  more than 20.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed support-v4-18.0.0.jar from libs folder and sync glade files again then my problem was fixed. Thanks @freshMan.