# Android appcompat-v7 themes_base.xml No resource found error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have been trying to import appcompat-v7 into my app and have had no luck at all. I need this library in order to follow the steps listed here [How do I use DrawerLayout to display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st). I have followed the steps documented https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html, and when I add the library to my project, I'm getting a list of errors:

```
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:140: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:139: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:137: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:134: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:135: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:144: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:148: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
```

I have the build target to API 21 for android-support-v7-appcompat. When I clean that project, I don't receive any errors. When I add appcompat-v7 as a library to my project, that is where the errors start appearing.

I have checked my SDK manager and everything is up to date. Can anyone help steer me in the right direction where I can resolve this issue?