# What exactly does fitsSystemWindows do?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm struggling to understand the concept of `fitsSystemWindows` as depending on the view it does different things. According to the official documentation it's a

> Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this view to **leave space for the system windows**.

Now, checking the `View.java` class I can see that when set to `true`, the window insets (status bar, navigation bar...) are applied to the view paddings, which works according to the documentation quoted above. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
private boolean fitSystemWindowsInt(Rect insets) {
    if ((mViewFlags & FITS_SYSTEM_WINDOWS) == FITS_SYSTEM_WINDOWS) {
        mUserPaddingStart = UNDEFINED_PADDING;
        mUserPaddingEnd = UNDEFINED_PADDING;
        Rect localInsets = sThreadLocal.get();
        if (localInsets == null) {
            localInsets = new Rect();
            sThreadLocal.set(localInsets);
        }
        boolean res = computeFitSystemWindows(insets, localInsets);
        mUserPaddingLeftInitial = localInsets.left;
        mUserPaddingRightInitial = localInsets.right;
        internalSetPadding(localInsets.left, localInsets.top,
                localInsets.right, localInsets.bottom);
        return res;
    }
    return false;
}
```

With the new Material design there are new classes which make extensive use of this flag and this is where the confusion comes. In many sources `fitsSystemWindows` is mentioned as the flag to set to lay the view behind the system bars. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440880/328616).

The documentation in `ViewCompat.java` for `setFitsSystemWindows` says:

> Sets whether or not this view should account for system screen decorations
>        such as the status bar and inset its content; **that is, controlling whether
>        the default implementation of {@link View#fitSystemWindows(Rect)} will be
>        executed. See that method for more details**.

According to this, `fitsSystemWindows` simply means that the function `fitsSystemWindows()` will be executed? The new Material classes seem to just use this for drawing under the status bar. If we look at `DrawerLayout.java`'s code, we can see this:

```
if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(this)) {
        IMPL.configureApplyInsets(this);
        mStatusBarBackground = IMPL.getDefaultStatusBarBackground(context);
    }
```

...

```
public static void configureApplyInsets(View drawerLayout) {
    if (drawerLayout instanceof DrawerLayoutImpl) {
        drawerLayout.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new InsetsListener());
        drawerLayout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

And we see the same pattern in the new `CoordinatorLayout` or `AppBarLayout`.

Doesn't this work in the exact opposite way as the documentation for `fitsSystemWindows`? In the last cases, it means **draw behind the system bars**.

However, if you want a `FrameLayout` to draw itself behind the status bar, setting `fitsSystemWindows` to true does not do the trick as the default implementation does what's documented initially. You have to override it and add the same flags as the other mentioned classes. Am I missing something?

Comment: This seems like a bug, I've posted a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195813) on the Android issue tracker

Comment: Check here: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec?linkId=19685562#.9k2ax354g

Comment: Thanks for the link, very useful. Still, it confirms that there are inconsistencies there. In the linked page it says that some of the new widgets, such as `CoordinatorLayout`, use that flag to infer if they should paint behind the status bar or not. That's not the case with `FrameLayout`, for example.

Comment: This was such a great question and very nice work looking into the Android source code. I particularly appreciated that you identified how the new MD classes handle fitsSystemWindows differently.... I was going crazy trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 37):

> System windows are the parts of the screen where the system is drawing
>   either non-interactive (in the case of the status bar) or interactive
>   (in the case of the navigation bar) content.
>
> Most of the time, your app won’t need to draw under the status bar or
>   the navigation bar, but if you do: you need to make sure interactive
>   elements (like buttons) aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the
>   default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows=“true” attribute
>   gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents
>   don’t overlay the system windows.

https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

Answer (score 11):

In short, if you're trying to figure out whether to use `fitsSystemWindows` or not, there's [Insetter](https://github.com/chrisbanes/insetter) library by Chris Banes (a developer from the Android team) which offers a better alternative to `fitsSystemWindows`. For more details let's see the explanation below.

There's a good article published by Android team in 2015 - [Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows?](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec). It well explains the default behavior of the attribute and how some layouts like DrawerLayout overrides it.

But, it was 2015. Back in 2017 at droidcon [Chris Banes](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes), who works on Android, [advised](https://youtu.be/_mGDMVRO3iE?t=889) not to use `fitSystemWindows` attribute unless a container documentation says to use it. And the reason for this is that the default behavior of the flag often doesn't meet your expectations. It's well explained in the video.

But what are these *special layouts* where you should use `fitsSystemWindows`? Well, it's `DrawerLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. These layouts override the default `fitsSystemWindows` behavior and treat it in a special way, again it's well explained in the video. Such different interpretation of the attribute sometimes leads to a confusion and questions like here. Actually, in [another video](https://chris.banes.dev/talks/2017/becoming-a-master-window-fitter-lon/) of droidcon London Chris Banes admits that the decision to overload the default behavior was a mistake (13:10 timestamp of the London conf).

Ok, if `fitSystemWindows` isn't the ultimate solution, what should be used? In [another article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windowinsets-listeners-to-layouts-8f9ccc8fa4d1) from 2019 Chris Banes suggests another solution, a few custom layout attributes based on [WindowInsets API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsCompat). For example, if you want a bottom-right FAB to margin from the navigation bar, you can easily configure it:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
  app:marginBottomSystemWindowInsets="@{true}"
  app:marginRightSystemWindowInsets="@{true}"
  ... />
```

The solution uses custom `@BindingAdapter`s, one for paddings and another for margins. The logic is well described in the [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windowinsets-listeners-to-layouts-8f9ccc8fa4d1) I've mentioned above. Some google samples use the solution, for example see [Owl](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/tree/develop/Owl) android material app, [BindingAdapters.kt](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/blob/develop/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/materialstudies/owl/util/BindingAdapters.kt). I just copy the adapter code here for a reference:

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter(
    "paddingLeftSystemWindowInsets",
    "paddingTopSystemWindowInsets",
    "paddingRightSystemWindowInsets",
    "paddingBottomSystemWindowInsets",
    requireAll = false
)
fun View.applySystemWindowInsetsPadding(
    previousApplyLeft: Boolean,
    previousApplyTop: Boolean,
    previousApplyRight: Boolean,
    previousApplyBottom: Boolean,
    applyLeft: Boolean,
    applyTop: Boolean,
    applyRight: Boolean,
    applyBottom: Boolean
) {
    if (previousApplyLeft == applyLeft &&
        previousApplyTop == applyTop &&
        previousApplyRight == applyRight &&
        previousApplyBottom == applyBottom
    ) {
        return
    }

    doOnApplyWindowInsets { view, insets, padding, _ ->
        val left = if (applyLeft) insets.systemWindowInsetLeft else 0
        val top = if (applyTop) insets.systemWindowInsetTop else 0
        val right = if (applyRight) insets.systemWindowInsetRight else 0
        val bottom = if (applyBottom) insets.systemWindowInsetBottom else 0

        view.setPadding(
            padding.left + left,
            padding.top + top,
            padding.right + right,
            padding.bottom + bottom
        )
    }
}

@BindingAdapter(
    "marginLeftSystemWindowInsets",
    "marginTopSystemWindowInsets",
    "marginRightSystemWindowInsets",
    "marginBottomSystemWindowInsets",
    requireAll = false
)
fun View.applySystemWindowInsetsMargin(
    previousApplyLeft: Boolean,
    previousApplyTop: Boolean,
    previousApplyRight: Boolean,
    previousApplyBottom: Boolean,
    applyLeft: Boolean,
    applyTop: Boolean,
    applyRight: Boolean,
    applyBottom: Boolean
) {
    if (previousApplyLeft == applyLeft &&
        previousApplyTop == applyTop &&
        previousApplyRight == applyRight &&
        previousApplyBottom == applyBottom
    ) {
        return
    }

    doOnApplyWindowInsets { view, insets, _, margin ->
        val left = if (applyLeft) insets.systemWindowInsetLeft else 0
        val top = if (applyTop) insets.systemWindowInsetTop else 0
        val right = if (applyRight) insets.systemWindowInsetRight else 0
        val bottom = if (applyBottom) insets.systemWindowInsetBottom else 0

        view.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            leftMargin = margin.left + left
            topMargin = margin.top + top
            rightMargin = margin.right + right
            bottomMargin = margin.bottom + bottom
        }
    }
}

fun View.doOnApplyWindowInsets(
    block: (View, WindowInsets, InitialPadding, InitialMargin) -> Unit
) {
    // Create a snapshot of the view's padding & margin states
    val initialPadding = recordInitialPaddingForView(this)
    val initialMargin = recordInitialMarginForView(this)
    // Set an actual OnApplyWindowInsetsListener which proxies to the given
    // lambda, also passing in the original padding & margin states
    setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->
        block(v, insets, initialPadding, initialMargin)
        // Always return the insets, so that children can also use them
        insets
    }
    // request some insets
    requestApplyInsetsWhenAttached()
}

class InitialPadding(val left: Int, val top: Int, val right: Int, val bottom: Int)

class InitialMargin(val left: Int, val top: Int, val right: Int, val bottom: Int)

private fun recordInitialPaddingForView(view: View) = InitialPadding(
    view.paddingLeft, view.paddingTop, view.paddingRight, view.paddingBottom
)

private fun recordInitialMarginForView(view: View): InitialMargin {
    val lp = view.layoutParams as? ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view layout params")
    return InitialMargin(lp.leftMargin, lp.topMargin, lp.rightMargin, lp.bottomMargin)
}

fun View.requestApplyInsetsWhenAttached() {
    if (isAttachedToWindow) {
        // We're already attached, just request as normal
        requestApplyInsets()
    } else {
        // We're not attached to the hierarchy, add a listener to
        // request when we are
        addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View) {
                v.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
                v.requestApplyInsets()
            }

            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View) = Unit
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see the realization isn't trivial. As I mentioned before, you're welcome to use [Insetter](https://github.com/chrisbanes/insetter) library by Chris Banes which offers the same functionality, see [insetter-dbx](https://github.com/chrisbanes/insetter#insetter-dbx).

Also note that WindowInsets API is going to change since version 1.5.0 of [androidx core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) library. For example `insets.systemWindowInsets` becomes `insets.getInsets(Type.systemBars() or Type.ime())`. See the library documentation and the [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d) for more details.

References:

- [Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows?](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec)
- [WindowInsets — listeners to layouts](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windowinsets-listeners-to-layouts-8f9ccc8fa4d1)
- [Animating your keyboard (part 1)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d)
- [Becoming a master window fitter (droidcon London 2017)](https://chris.banes.dev/talks/2017/becoming-a-master-window-fitter-lon/)
- [Becoming a master window fitter (droidcon NYC 2017)](https://youtu.be/_mGDMVRO3iE)

Answer (score 10):

it does not draw behind the system bar
it kind of stretches behind the bar to tint it with the same colors it has but the views it contains is padded inside the status bar
if that makes sense