# transparent statusbar navigationdrawer after setstatusbarcolor

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm try to developing an app with a navigation drawer from a template found on github.

In `style.xml` i have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0000ff</item>
```

[image: main]

and the status bar in navigation drawer is ok.
[image: main]

When i click the button it runs this command:
`getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.GREEN);`
[image: main]

Now the status bar color in navigation drawer is no more translucent
[image: main]

How restore status bar color to translucent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the xml defined colors `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` are not really used to directly set the status bar color.

Actually the statusbar is completely transparent all the time and only the underlaying `View` is colored. Thats why it can have another color on the left than on the right side (have a look at your second screenshot). If you now call `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(..)` you indeed *color the statusbar directly* and over-draw the color of both `Views`. So it needs to stay transparent!

What you really want to do, is changing the color of the View underlaying the status bar, which is done with the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` class.
Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st/27153313#27153313) and [this class from the library you provided](https://bitbucket.org/dvdandroid/material-drawer/src/9e339003c48bc3b6cbf7e7b326270bb9d48fd109/app/src/main/java/com/poliveira/apps/materialtests/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java?at=master)
There you should find all the necessary information to change only the color of the area you want to.

---

In case you really just want to reset the color:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```