# How to make fragment overlay toolbar in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I have a `material design navigation drawer` i created from [this tutorial.](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

It works perfect with `toolbar` and all. I can click on an item in the drawer and the respective `fragment` is displayed plus the title.

However i would like to make the `toolbar` on one `fragment` to be transparent so that the background image is displayed like in the image below:
[image]

**PROBLEM:** My problem is the fragment doesnt seem to start over the toolbar but below it.This is the result:[image]

I dont know how to fix this.Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: [How do I use DrawerLayout to display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar? - Stack Overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st

Comment: No that's not what i want to achieve.

Comment: I know how to do what you have suggested above.But the problem is not with the drawe but with the fragment displayed.

Comment: @SteveKamau  any luck with this?

Comment: @linisax none, gave up on it

Comment: @SteveKamau I am having the exact same problem! Can you tell me if you have resolved it and if so how?

Comment: @amateurprogrammer simply create a transparent toolbar, then toggle the background from transparent to your primary colour on the appropriate fragment.

Comment: @SteveKamau I tried that but I wasn't getting the result, can you post what you came up with as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/toolbar_image"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Of course, you'll need to change "@drawable/toolbar_image" to the drawable that you want to use for the background image.