# Navigation drawer still not appearing over toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation

I am following an Android for beginner's book which despite being quite new, is still out of date in a few areas. I'm making my first app with a navigation drawer, and have found that the method it uses to implement a nav drawer has since been superseded.

Using the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30525387/1703330) I have managed a certain amount of success - where before the top item in the nav drawer was completely obscured by the toolbar, now it is only partially obscured - but I want the nav drawer to appear *above* the toolbar completely. I have tried moving bits of XML around but to no avail. Here's my layout code:

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Layout to hold fragments loaded by navdrawer-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/nav" /> <!-- The items to display -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.interglobalmegacorp.whereitssnap.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's what happens:
[Screenshot link because I don't have enough rep to embed yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTWft.png)

My only thought is that it might be something to do with the theme, which is currently set to NoActionBar, because anything else seems to crash the app:

`This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT onCreate() method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout); // bind the layout
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString(); // get the title of the app and store it


        // set up the drawer with our purpose-built method
        setupDrawer();

        // set up the nav drawer toggle
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // listen for clicks on navdrawer
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switchFragment(item);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // load default fragment
        Fragment fragment = new TitlesFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment, "TITLES").commit();
    }
```

Comment: It's not your theme. It's just the layouts. You want the `DrawerLayout` as the outermost `View`. Then the `CoordinatorLayout` should be the first child of the `DrawerLayout`, and your `fragmentHolder` `RelativeLayout` would go in place of the `<include>`. The other `RelativeLayout` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According guidelines your *Drawerlayout* should contains your *Coordinatorlayout*.

About first *RealativeLayout* in code you should remove it.

Try with this:

**content_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav" /> <!-- The items to display -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.interglobalmegacorp.whereitssnap.MainActivity">

    <!-- Layout to hold fragments into activity-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**onCreate()**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout); // bind the layout
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString(); // get the title of the app and store it

    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switchFragment(item);
                return true;
            }
        });

    // load default fragment
    Fragment fragment = new TitlesFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment, "TITLES").commit();

}
```

Comment: Where should I put the RelativeLayout (my id fragHolder) that actually holds the Fragments the NavDrawer loads?

Comment: You can add app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" into Navigation view

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense to me at all. I've tried using the code above and it's basically causing the app to crash - the MainActivity code can no longer find the various layout elements it needs, e.g. the Navigation View.

Comment: Post your onCreate() method.

Comment: @moralesbatovski By 'the fragments the navdrawer loads' I mean the main part of the app, the actual 'pages' of the app, not the items in the navdrawer itself

Comment: Ok, then all this code (fragments, etc) should be included in activity_main.xml. Think about "DrawerLayout" only as a container that contains two elements: your NavigationView and your Activity. Check EDIT on activity_main.xml

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Still getting a nasty error though: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference`

Comment: You should initialize your "NavigationView"

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing with `mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);`?

Comment: Replace setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) by setContentView(R.layout.content_main)

Comment: Ah ha! That's got it! Thank you very much!