# Setting navigation drawer on top of other fragments

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-relativelayout

I have an activity that used a Relativelayout in its screen. Also there is a navigation drawer in my screen. This is my [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on5BS.jpg)

A problem is happened, when navigation drawer opened, the elements of Relativelayout placed on top of navigation drawer. So I need to solve this problem by setting my navigation on top of other elements.

Please help me.
Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_main"
tools:context="ir.kaasbarg.khoms.MainActivity" >


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<!-- The main content view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 

/>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_gravity="end"

   >

    <!-- Profile Box -->
    <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#202020" 

        />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btndate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
    android:text="تاریخ سال خمسی"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnitems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
    android:text = "موارد خمس"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnkhoms"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
    android:text="محاسبه ی خمس"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnhelp"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
    android:text="راهنما"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnexit"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
    android:text="خروج"
    android:textSize="25sp" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml file? I guess it's because you need to move your navigation drawer to the bottom of the xml

Comment: Yes. I moved this, but I get a run time error!

Comment: please post the xml file, I can't answer your question in the dark

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use DrawerLayout to display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are part of the content, so they should be inside DrawerLayout. When using NavigationDrawer/NavigationView, DrawerLayout should be the root view and the content should be added inside it, not outside. You can read more about this in this [post](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2016/07/13/android-navigation-view-tabs/#activityMain).

So your file should look like this:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
        android:text="تاریخ سال خمسی"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnitems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
        android:text = "موارد خمس"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnkhoms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
        android:text="محاسبه ی خمس"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnhelp"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
        android:text="راهنما"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnexit"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
        android:text="خروج"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="end"

        >

        <!-- Profile Box -->
        <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="#202020"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

change your layout like below layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main"
    tools:context="ir.kaasbarg.khoms.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btndate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
                android:text="تاریخ سال خمسی"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnitems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
                android:text="موارد خمس"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnkhoms"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
                android:text="محاسبه ی خمس"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnhelp"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
                android:text="راهنما"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnexit"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_main1"
                android:text="خروج"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"

            >

            <!-- Profile Box -->
            <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/navList"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="#202020"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this cool library https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

if you want to customize just create your own adapter or inform me, i will help sharing my code with you.

[image: Material drawer demo]

[image: Material drawer demo 2]

Comment: he is not ask for any library.
he just ask for a drawer issue .