# Android AppCompatActivity not showing toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

In my app I have a Main Activity with a drawer layout to navigate between two fragments. One of those fragments has a FAB which opens another activity that extends from AppCompatActivity. This activity shows no lower toolbar, and an upper toolbar in grey. I managed to add a lower toolbar in the xml code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/editor_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="Add Manual Entry"/>
```

but the upper toolbar keeps showing in grey no matter what. Tried setting the upper toolbar to my colorPrimaryDark as a workaround but found no way to do it. I looked into my AppTheme and found this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Seeing as the parent says no action bar, I tried changing it to Theme.AppCompat.Light but I get this error on my main activity: 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tobias.run/com.example.tobias.run.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

which looks like my MainActivity and its drawer layout require the NoActionBar theme, altough I'm not sure. Why does my secondary activity doesn't come with a toolbar? how can I add one?

PS: Both the secondary activity code and xml are just as how Android Studio created them with the empty activity template. the xml just had the toolbar added.

Answer (score 2):

This means that you already have included a toolbar somewhere in your view hierarchy (you have not provided your complete layout, so hard to say).
In any case, just paste these two lines in your code (`OnCreate` of your Actvity) and mostly this should fix your problem.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Oh yes, revert back the other changes that you did to supply the action bar.**

The toolbar reference might be different if you have specifically changed it in your layout. The default is always given an id `toolbar`
Android sometime back revamped the whole action bar thing and made it more generic. So what you include in your layout is a generic toolbar which does not show up as a actionbar unless you set it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

OR

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and in you Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: This is the last line in the error he got  - `Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`  I think google suggests going the toolbar way going ahead for flexibility sake.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a workaround. The issue was the 
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`
in the AppTheme. When setting it to transparent, the status bar fades to transparent when activating the drawer layout, which is the desired result. But when you create a new activity the status bar looks exactly as your background, making it look like there's no status bar. To make it work, I left the attr transparent in the App Theme for the Drawer Layout but changed during runtime, in my other activity, the color of my status bar following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st/).