# How to make custom navigation bar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-animation

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9aRx.png)

First image  is view of my main activity and i want navigation drawer as shown in second image. can anyone help with this how i can implement this
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iigr.png)

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st

Comment: Its not helpful can you please look at images provided by me.